# Angularfire2 query a list

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am not able to make simple list query with AngularFire2.
This is the structure of my database.

[image: database structure]

Each number has an object inside with the desired fields.

Querying an object gives me the correct result this way:

```
db.object('whatevernumber').valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
      console.log(items);
    });
```

and I get the following, which is correct
[image]

But what I want is to get all objects under "playas-espana" as an array. 
I have tried with something like this without any luck.

```
 items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('/playas-espana').valueChanges();
  }
```

How could it be done? Thanks in advance!

Updated: 
Here more clearly where playas-espana is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does this `this.items = db.list('/playas-espana').valueChanges();` give you?

Comment: an empty array: [ ]

Comment: @CarlosHernándezGil I think you need to subscribe to the `valueChanges()` method

Comment: Yes, I have done it:   db.list('/playas-espana').valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
      console.log(items);
    });

Comment: is `playas-espana` under the root node?

Comment: I have updated my question to show where playas-espana exactly is

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
db.list('/playas-espana').valueChanges().subscribe(items => { 
    console.log(items); 
});
```

will return you the collection of objects, all the child nodes with its unique keys like

```
3291 :{}
3XXX :{}
3X54 :{}
```

So you need to get each object key to access the particular object from the `this.items`

```
private list = any[] = [];


db.list('/playas-espana').valueChanges().subscribe(items => { 
  if(items) {
     let keys = Object.keys(items);
     keys.forEach(element => {
        let obj = items[element];
        this.list.push(obj);
     }
     console.log(list); // Use it anywhere
  }
});
```

> EDIT:

```
private list = any[] = [];

db.ref('/playas-espana').once('value', (snapshot) => {
     var items = snapshot.val();
     if (items != null) {
          Object.keys(items).forEach(element => {
          let item = items[element];
          this.list.push(item);
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: db.list('/playas-espana').valueChanges().subscribe(items => { console.log(items); }); is returning only an empty array: [ ]

Comment: @PreshantPimpale now snapshot.val() returns null

Comment: @CarlosHernándezGil Is there any other queries working in the application?

Comment: ,no, the only one is the object query. I have tried a lot of things. I have imported the database manually from a JSON files, and it generated the numbers, perhaps should I load the database programatically in order to get the typical string "key" in firebase